# “Copy link” button doesn’t work in responsive mobile Safari

Tags: bug, status-norepro, responsive-design, share-this, mobile-safari

A recent update added a “copy link” button when the share menu is open on posts. However, in the responsive site on mobile Safari, this button doesn’t work. This could be fixed if a different method were used (maybe [Clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/), which works on mobile Safari).

Comment: What version of iOS / Safari?

Comment: I tested just now and can reproduce on Safari and Chrome. I'm on iOS 12.3.1 it seems.

Comment: @Shog9 iOS 12.4

Comment: Ok. So, apparently this is expected behavior; [mobile safari just makes it 10x more work than any sensible browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios/34046084#34046084)

Comment: @Shog9 yes. Trying the clipboard.js website’s examples, it works fine on mobile Safari. Seems like a quite good and pretty simple solution (but I sound like a spammer XD).

Comment: Yeah, clipboard.js is cool. Sorta felt like overkill when it's like two lines of code for most browsers, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now! I don’t know what changed—it is either Safari in iOS 13 changed or the devs changed this to another system. Either way, here’s a screenshot:

[image: it works, as shown in a screenshot of Safari mobile]

Comment: I closed this as `status-norepro` because it appears we don't have `status-obselete`. LMK if you see it happening again and we'll reopen. Thanks!

Comment: @MeganRisdal oh, was this something that changed on Apple's end, then? Thanks!