# Why is the "copy link" option not available in mobile web view of "share" popup?

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web, share-this

The "copy link" option is available in the "share" popup of the browser version, but it is not available in the mobile web view.

Can the "copy link" option be added in the mobile web view too?

Current screenshot of the "share" popup in mobile web view:

> [image: Mobile web]

Comment: [Copying links has problems with Safari](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332795/399694), so this may be unlikely.

Comment: Text is already selected. Just click again on input and click the copy button.

Comment: For me clicking on that selected text un-selects it.

Comment: @Stormblessed we just should ask isers to use a real browser, like Edge for example....

Comment: @Stormblessed what about non-Safari users?

Comment: @marcellothearcane Well I’m not saying that this shouldn’t be implemented, but I’m noting that the developers might ignore this because [mobile Safari is used by about 50% of mobile web users in America](https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/08/06/safari-still-leads-in-mobile-browser-share-but-facebooks-browser-is-on-the-rise).